# Python How do I assigning a variable name with an HTML list to a (method?)

Tags: python, html, flask, reddit, praw

please forgive my poorly worded title as I am still learning Python.
The problem is that in my Python script, I want the .hot to be replaced by a variable called instance which has a selection of options from my HTML file. Unfortunately, for some reason I don't yet understand, I can't just replace 'hot' with 'instance' or str(instance()). If someone could help me with a solution that would be great!

Thank you

Here is the Python Script in question

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def index_post():
    subreddit = request.form['subreddit']
    instance = request.form['instance']
    num = request.form['limit']
    news = []
    i = 0
    for submission in reddit.subreddit(subreddit).hot(limit=int(num)):
        i += 1
        news.append(str(i) + '. ' + submission.title)
    return render_template("index.html", news=news)
```

Here is my HTML template.

```
<!doctype html>

<form action="." method="POST">
    Subreddit name:
    <input type="text" name="subreddit" placeholder="Topic">

    Instance:
    <select name="instance">
      <option value="controversial">Controversial</option>
      <option value="gilded">Gilded</option>
      <option value="hot">Hot</option>
      <option value="new">New</option>
      <option value="rising">Rising</option>
      <option value="top">Top</option>
    </select>

    Limit:
    <input type="number" name="limit">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>

{% for item in news %}
    <p> {{item}} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you want to do something like this:

```
redditFunction = getattr(reddit.subreddit(subreddit), instance)
for submission in redditFunction(limit=int(num)):
    ...
```

When `instance` is `new` this should call

reddit.subreddit(subreddit).new(limit=int(num))

`gettattr` gets the attribute on the first argument passed to it that is named with the second attribute. So you will get the function that is named in the `instance` variable, which (hopefully) is the function you are trying to call.